# Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'app' option is required for reinstall

Tags: appium

I need your help. I want to connect the device locally (not an emulator). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tDIF.png)

But I stopped at this problem that I can't solve.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy5Bt.png)

Answer (score 1):

If your app is not installed on the test device then you need to provide `appium:app` capability with the path to the `*.apk` file. If your app is already installed on the device then you can try adding `appium:noReset` capability with value `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It turned out to be much easier than I thought. I didn't specify practically anything in capability except platformName,Device Name and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

hey have you tried adding this capability?

```
desired_caps['appWaitActivity'] = '*'
```

for pycharm and

```
appium:appWaitActivity text *
```

into appiuminspector
this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I managed to launch appium with a locally connected device.